# C# - How to avoid multiple if calls

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have the following code

```
var response = emailValidation();
if(response.Successful) response = emailContentLoad();
if(response.Successful) response = emailPlaceholdersLoad();
// Possibly more calls
if(response.Successful) response = sendEmail();

return response
```

The four methods return a `Response` object, which has a `Successful` property indicating if any exceptions where thrown during the execution.

And while I do get the purpose of that I was wondering if there is a better way to do it?, maybe a pattern, but without harming readability.

Comment: also what does `method1, method2, method3, and method4` look like.. you need to learn how to use bool values to check and assign .. this is a poor question at best and makes absolutely `ZERO SENSE`

Comment: how many cases  you have?

Comment: @CyberProgs this question warrants not further questioning in it's current state it literally makes zero sense

Comment: @MethodMan because if he has only few cases there is nothing wrong using switch/ if statement otherwise he can use something like lookup table

Comment: @CyberProgs there is _literally_ only two cases (`true/false`). Why would you use a switch for a boolean value?

Comment: @CyberProgs I think you need to read the code and follow the logic.. your comment makes no sense based on the fact that question makes no sense

Comment: @maccettura I am talking about condition /cases no true/ false and I  assume he just write the code in the question for illustration because the code itself doesn't make sense

Comment: @maccettura, is like a template method, each execution the response is the result of the new operation;

Comment: @MethodMan I'm sorry I'll try to update it with more information, but I can precisely disclose the code, also then number of methods is not fixed, can very from 4 - 10+

Comment: you need to show a example of some code it does not have to be exact code but it should depict a relative example of what you are trying to do..

Comment: @MethodMan I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions at the moment.

#### First solution - more close the code sample you have shown.

In the code sample you are mutating the same variable in several steps, depending on the previous result. This can be really easy represent as sequence of operations (assuming all of the methods have the same signature). Something like this.

```
// sequence of the methods that will be chained WITHOUT the first method
var operations = new List<Fuc<...>>()
{
   method2,
   method3,
   method4,
};
// returns the first failed operation or the the last operation from the
// operations list
var result = 
   operations
      .Aggregate(
         seed: method1(), 
         func: (seed, op) => seed.Successful ? op() : seed
      );
```

This way you can easily add new operations in the operations list.

And if you are not such fan of LINQ:

```
var operations = new List<Func<...>>()
{
   method2,
   method3,
   method4,
};

var response = method1();
foreach(var op in operations)
{
  if(response.Successful)
  {
    response = op();
  }
  else 
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

#### Second solution - general solution for chaining methods that can fail.

You can check the **[Option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)** (concept popular in functional languages)

Check this [github project](https://github.com/nlkl/Optional) for c# implementation and explanation.

[This](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) can give you another prespective (lang: F#)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to chain these all together:

```
Response response = EmailContentLoad().EmailPlaceholdersLoad().SendEmail();
```

The methods would look something like this:

```
public static Response EmailContentLoad(this Response response)
{
    if(!response.Successful)
    {
        return response;
    }
    //Do whatever the method normally does
}
```

This is a bit more readable and extensible, now you can call your methods in any order (if you want) and you wont have to maintain a single function of chained if statements.

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8XM6v) to illustrate.

Comment: I really like this approach but it would require to change lots of classes that already use the previous approach, although the use of extension methods would make it easier

Comment: @J.Pichardo I added a fiddle to illustrate more of what I mean

Comment: Yeah I see now, let me try it

Comment: This way he will have the same amount if statements, also Response could be returned from a lots of methods in big project (or eventually will) which overall will lead to shifting a lot of logic into extension methods .. which maybe is a bad idea. Just thought - important to be noted.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a pattern but you could write it like this:

```
var response = emailValidation();
if(!response.Successful) return response;

response = emailContentLoad();
if(!response.Successful) return response;

response = emailPlaceholdersLoad();
if(!response.Successful) return response;

response = sendEmail();
return response
```

You still have the same number of if statements but the function terminates as soon as an error occurs and uneeded checks will be avoided.

As a recommendation i would not catch all exceptions inside these methods. Instead i would catch them where you want to handle it or where you want to show an error message to the user. So you could simplify your code to:

```
public void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        var response = SendMyMail();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Show error message to user
    }
}

public Response SendMyMail()
{
    emailValidation();
    emailContentLoad();
    emailPlaceholdersLoad();
    return sendEmail();
}
```